# NGINX API request using wrong value for IP

Tags: nginx

I'm making a request from my dev server to Google's Distance Matrix API to determine the distance from a given postcode to the client's restaurant address for delivery eligibility. The code works fine and has done for a couple of years, and is currently functional on the live site. It's a pretty standard GET request using WordPress's wp_remote_get method:

```
function google_get_distance( $ori, $dest ) {
        $key = get_option( 'ep_theme_options' )[ 'ep_gm_distance_matrix_api' ];
        $dist_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric' .
                        '&origins=' . urlencode( $ori ) . '&destinations=' . urlencode( $dest ) . '&key=' . $key;
        $response = wp_remote_get( $dist_url );
        return $response;
}
```

However, I recently redid my dev server from the ground up and something's come unglued in the switch, and Google is now denying my dev server's requests. The response has a 200 code, and the body follows from my error logs:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
Request received from IP address 2a05:d01c:134:a400:114e:f664:c4ef:9601,
with referer: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=XXX&destinations=XXX&key=XXX",
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

It looks like the IP address is wrong, and I suspect Nginx isn't configured properly to provide the IP address correctly. A quick google of the error message shows that the IP address in this message should indeed be a typical IP address rather than whatever I'm seeing here. Server config isn't my strongest area as I only ever really mess with it to get sites working with minimal tweaking and then leave it alone, so any suggestion as to what's going on here would be much appreciated. I should probably also mention that the dev server's IP address hasn't changed so the one permitted for this key is still valid, as all I've done is re-assign my public IP address from one Lightsail instance to another on AWS. I can provide various bits of global Nginx configuration if anyone can tell me what snippets etc. would be of use. Here's the site's specific Nginx config:

```
server {


    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
#    ssl on;
#    listen 80;
#    listen [::]:80;
    server_name ep.itruns.co.uk;

    rewrite ^/blog / permanent;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/itruns.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/itruns.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;


#    access_log /var/log/nginx/ep.itruns.co.uk.access.log rt_cache;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/ep.itruns.co.uk.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ep.itruns.co.uk.error.log;


    root /var/www/ep;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Disable standard php7 includes so we can add adjust auth_basic inheritance
    # include common/php7.conf;

    # Adding auth_basic within our location / block so it's not inherited for wp-json
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
      auth_basic "Are You Really Supposed To Be Here?";
      auth_basic_user_file /var/www/ep/.htpasswd;
    }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
#        location ~ \.php$ {
#                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
 #               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  #      }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whatever the reason of this problem is, it isn't related to your nginx config, nginx isn't involved in any way with the `GET` request that is being made by your server to the `maps.googleapis.com`.

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. This just shows how far my server config knowledge goes! Any suggestions as to where else I might try looking? PHP config maybe?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Change your question tags to `google-maps` and `php` to draw an attention from someone more experienced with google maps API.